# JGoogleAnalyticsTracker initialization failure in UML Designer plugin

Tags: uml-designer

I am getting a repeated error while using OBEO UML-Designer plugin version 6.0.0.2 for Eclipse Mars. There is a setting in Eclipse Preferences under Windows-Preferences-Sirius-UML Designer Usage - the check box that indicates whether collection of data is allowed or disallowed, in my case the box is unchecked, so it should not attempt to collect the data. However, it appears trying to collect the data and fails for some reason as indicated below:

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui.workbench 4 2 2016-11-22 15:39:08.529
!MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.ui.workbench".
!STACK 0
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.dmurph.tracking.JGoogleAnalyticsTracker (initialization failure)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializationAlreadyFailed(J9VMInternals.java:87)
    at org.obeonetwork.dsl.uml2.usage.analytics.SiriusEditorsListener.(SiriusEditorsListener.java:67)
    at org.obeonetwork.dsl.uml2.usage.analytics.UsageStartup$1.windowActivated(UsageStartup.java:65)

Multiple occurences of the same error are logged by Eclipse. Can someone help to resolve the issues, please?

your help is greatly appreciated!
thanks,
victor

Answer (score 0):

I add a new issue in the UML Designer tracker, I will try to fix it for the next 7.2.0 version: https://github.com/ObeoNetwork/UML-Designer/issues/902

You should know that even if you have an error we do not track anything when you unchecked the preference.

Thanks for your feedback!